# Image preview with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following problem:

I want to make an image preview for uploaded images with `<input type="file">`.
For that I need to get all images from the input which is no problem.

**I came so far:**

```
async handleFileInput(event: any) {

      this.filesToUpload = event.target.files;

        let test = await this.images(event);
        this.fileUrl = test;       
    }

    async images(event)
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
            for (var i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++)
            {
               reader.onload = (event: any) => {
                    var data = event.target.result;
                    resolve(data);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[i]);
            }
        });
    }
```

But I can not find out how to get all images which were uploaded with `Promise`. With only one image everthing works fine. But how can I get all of them ?

When I enter more than one image I get the following error:

```
 Uncaught (in promise): InvalidStateError:
 An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
```

I know that I have to use an array if I want to `resolve` more than one image. I just wanted to show a working example. 
The problem is that I can only declare variables inside `onload`. So everything will be overwritten when the second image is uploaded.

The reason why I want to do that is that I can bind to the image urls like that:

```
<div *ngFor="let fileUrl of fileUrls">
    <img [src]="fileUrl">
</div>
```

Thank you for your help. I hope there is a working solution out there.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48939922/1009922).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preview multiple image before upload file in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48939699/preview-multiple-image-before-upload-file-in-angular)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I import DomSanitizer:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Add it to the constructor:

```
constructor(
     public sanitizer: DomSanitizer
){}
```

Then loop over the files array like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let fileUrl of fileUrls;let i=index">
      <img *ngIf="fileUrl[i]"[src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(fileUrl[i])">
 </div>
```

DomSanitizer ensures you're not open to cross-site scripting hacks, for example, someone passing a URL to a malicious JavaScript script to have code execute on your page.

Comment: Isn't it that you explicitly bypass that security mechanism with your provided answer? You are telling the sanitizer to trust the value you are passing. This breaks the security mechanism. The approach would rather be to use sanitizer.sanitize with a security context, right?