# How to get the first image url from multiple selected image files in Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am new to angular 4 ,Here in need to display the first image of the selected image files before upload.

I have searched and found a solution on stackoverflow but I can't get the first image url. It displayed all the images as selected.

Reference : [Preview multiple image before upload file in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48939699/preview-multiple-image-before-upload-file-in-angular)

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {

    urls = new Array<string>();
    selectedImageToShow : string ;

      detectFiles(event) {

        selectedImageToShow = // how to get the first image url 

        this.urls = [];
        let files = event.target.files;
        if (files) {
          for (let file of files) {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (e: any) => {
              this.urls.push(e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

app.component.html

```
<div>
    <img *ngFor="let url of urls" [src]="url" class="rounded mb-3" width="180">
</div>
<input type="file" multiple (change)="detectFiles($event)">
```

can anyone help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app.component.html should look more like this:

```
// iterate over all the urls in the urls array
<div *ngFor ="let url of urls; let i=index">
  // only show the image if the urls index in the array is less than 1
  <div *ngIf="i < 1">
    <img [src]="url" class="rounded mb-3" width="180">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there any other way to get the first image using typescript code instead of using HTML side @user2263572

Comment: When iterating through the files, you could store the first file in a separate variable.  And then set the img [src]='first_file_var'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the file index to get first file name.

Your `files` is an array and you can loop or grab with index as below:

```
let first_file = event.target.files[0]; // without loop. Use name property for file name

let file_name = "";

// Using loop
for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
  file_name = files[i]; // use index 0 to store first file.
}
```