# Angular upload and preview multiple image

Tags: javascript, html, angular, file, file-upload

I want to upload and preview multiple images when create a new object on my angular app, the upload work only for one image, how to fix my code to let it upload multiple file !

---

```
  <div class="row flex-row justify-content-centerr">
            <div class="col-md-3 mt-2 btn radius btn-secondary inputbtn1" (click)="triggerInput1()">
              <input #file1 type="file" accept='image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg' id="file1"
                (change)="setImage1(file1.files)" multiple/>
              <label>
                <i class="la la-plus-square"> {{'plaintes.nouvelle.photos' | translate}} </i>
              </label>
              <label for="file1" style="display: none">
                <i class="la la-plus-square"> {{'plaintes.nouvelle.photos' | translate}} </i>
              </label>
            </div>



          </div>
          <div class="row flex-row justify-content-centerr">
            <div class="col-md-3 mt-2" *ngIf="imgURL1">
              <figure class="img-hover-01">
                <img [src]="imgURL1" class="img-fluid" alt="..." height="150">
                <div>
                  <a [href]="imgURL1" data-lity="" data-lity-desc="..." height="150"></a>
                  <a href="javascript:;"><i class="la la-trash-o" (click)="resetInput1()"></i></a>
                </div>
              </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 mt-2" *ngIf="imgURL2">
              <figure class="img-hover-01">
                <img [src]="imgURL2" class="img-fluid" alt="..." height="150">
                <div>
                  <a [href]="imgURL2" data-lity="" data-lity-desc="..." height="150"></a>
                  <a (click)="resetInput2()" href="javascript:;"><i class="la la-trash-o"></i></a>
                </div>
              </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 mt-2" *ngIf="imgURL3">
              <figure class="img-hover-01">
                <img [src]="imgURL3" class="img-fluid" alt="..." height="150">
                <div>
                  <a [href]="imgURL3" data-lity="" data-lity-desc="..." height="150"></a>
                  <a (click)="resetInput3()" href="javascript:;"><i class="la la-trash-o"></i></a>
                </div>
              </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 mt-2" *ngIf="imgURL4">
              <figure class="img-hover-01">
                <img [src]="imgURL4" class="img-fluid" alt="..." height="150">
                <div>
                  <a [href]="imgURL4" data-lity="" data-lity-desc="..." height="150"></a>
                  <a (click)="resetInput4()" href="javascript:;"><i class="la la-trash-o"></i></a>
                </div>
              </figure>
            </div>
          </div>
```

---

```
  triggerInput1() {
    $('#file1').click();
  }


  setImage1(files) {
    this.fileToUpload1 = files.item(0);
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    reader.onload = _event => {
      this.imgURL1 = reader.result;
    };
    this.fileToUpload2 = files.item(1);
    const readerr = new FileReader();
    readerr.readAsDataURL(files[1]);
    readerr.onload = _event => {
      this.imgURL2 = readerr.result;
    };
    this.fileToUpload2 = files.item(2);
    const readerrr = new FileReader();
    readerrr.readAsDataURL(files[2]);
    readerrr.onload = _event => {
      this.imgURL3 = readerrr.result;
    };
    this.fileToUpload2 = files.item(3);
    const readerrrr = new FileReader();
    readerrrr.readAsDataURL(files[3]);
    readerrrr.onload = _event => {
      this.imgURL4 = readerrrr.result;
    };

  }
```

I've defined on input and 4 previews, I can't figure out why it doesn't work the multiple upload 
despite that working  with a single image

Comment: You may find ideas in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48939699/1009922).

Comment: You haven't said whether it's the preview or the upload that doesn't work, nor exactly what you mean by "doesn't work". If your problem is with the upload, perhaps you could add your code that does the upload?

Comment: Hope this will help:https://therichpost.com/preview-image-in-angular-7-before-upload/